# Port forwarding on google compute?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to setup a few minecraft servers for my kids and have installed everything and technically the servers are running but we can't connect ... From what I've found searching around it seems like you potentially have to do some port forwarding to ensure things flow through. I've already got a firewall rule setup but this does not seem to be working.

I'm running both a regular minecraft server as well as pocketmine-mp for mobile. Same challenge on both servers ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not general computing questions.  If you provide more information, such as what firewall rules you have, this may have better traction over at [SU].

Comment: Thanks for the answer and guidance on the other forum. Will give it a go.